# need to make my partners pill box turnover sensitive

Tags: gyroscope

ive done some arduino stuff back in uni like 7 years ago; and reserached premade items-ive looked online at many pill organisers and the best and cheapest one is $149 and isn't shipping to the UK rite now. but basically my partner needs to take 1 pill a day without fail. second set of pills is less urgent and not an issue if he misses, but basically is there like a thing I could whip together to sense when he has turned the pill case over that day or not? maybe sync to phone(would be super useful)  so he knows when he has actually taken it.

Comment: yes, there is probably something that you could build .... it is unclear how you would detect that the pill was actually swallowed

Comment: Is this a pill case that holds pills for 7 days? Surely the absence of a pill on a certain day indicates that at least it has been removed from the case (and hopefully swallowed). The "has the box turned over" gadget wouldn't prove the pill had been swallowed anyway.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't go with a "turn-over" sensor, but would just use a (big) button. I'd go with something like an ESP8266/ESP32. Those can connect to WiFi. Then have it send a push notification when being pressed (that is; the pill has been taken). Maybe light up an LED to also indicate the pill has been taken. Turn off the led at midnight. Also send a different notification when the button hasn't been pressed before, say noon.

For push notifications, you can use PushSafer, PushBullet, or Prowl (which I had most success with).

Have a look at Kevin Darrah [article](https://www.kevindarrah.com/wiki/index.php?title=TrigBoardV7), and youtube channel. He uses it's own boards, but most of the code will work on any ESP board.

But try to imaging how the system would work, in your head first. Just throwing technology at a problem isn't always the best solution. My grandma has 7 pill boxes, one for each week. Which helped to keep track of whether a pill was taken that day.

Best of luck.